# Jenkins on Windows - Matlab Doesn't Exit

Tags: windows, matlab, jenkins, build, continuous-integration

The following command on Jenkins freestyle doesn't exit(runs forever) in Windows environment. However when I run the same command in CMD it works as expected.

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -minimize -c "path_to_license" -r "run('path_to_run_all_tests_script')" -wait -logfile unittestlog.txt set output=%errorlevel% MORE unittestlog.txt EXIT %output%
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

This is the Matlab script that the command calls:

```
import matlab.unittest.TestSuite;

disp('Hello from TestSuite');
try
    suite = TestSuite.fromPackage('test','IncludingSubpackages',true);
    results = run(suite);
    display(results);
catch e
    disp(getReport(e,'extended'));
    exit(1);
end
exit(any([results.Failed])+1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that this is a licensing issue - you need Jenkins to be running as the same user that is named in the MATLAB license (assuming of course that your MATLAB license is a named-user license - if it's a concurrent or named-machine license, please ignore me).

If it's the wrong user, then MATLAB will start up, but show a dialog box telling you of the licensing issue. However, since you've called it with `-nodesktop`, this dialog will not be visible, and MATLAB will then just hang around for ever as a "zombie" process without sending a return value to Jenkins. If you go into Task Manager, you may find that you have one or more of them hanging around, and you can force-quit them there.

Note that you should be careful about the licensing requirements if you're running MATLAB for unit testing or automated builds via Jenkins. If you have a named-user license, only that named user is allowed to use it, and that includes via Jenkins. So long as you're the only person who can kick off a Jenkins/MATLAB job, that's fine - but if you're exposing Jenkins to several users, all of whom can kick off a MATLAB job, you're violating the license agreement. If you need to do that, you should really acquire a concurrent license for Jenkins to run under. But it's a bit of a grey area, you might want to speak to your account manager about it.

Hope that helps!

---

Edit: I think you might also want to take a look at the exit codes you're using in your test script. You want MATLAB to exit with a success code of zero when the tests pass, and a non-zero failure code when the tests fail, or when an error occurs during testing. So you probably want your last line to be `exit(any([results.Failed]));`, not `exit(any([results.Failed])+1);`.

Comment: Yeah, solved already, it was about license and Jenkins was not using licensed user.

Comment: In my case on Win10 the "Run as user" field for the service has the format `myuser@companydomain` by choosing the user from the browse window. Somehow it causes the license error and had to be replaced by `companydomain\myuser`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was related to licensing. Jenkins should be run by the same user who has Matlab license.

In addition to Sam Roberts answer: To change Jenkins's user, go to ***services*** in ***computer management***, find the Jenkins service and change the user from ***properties***.